# Remote connectivity to Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server

Hi 
I am newbie to windows server 2003. Trying to develop Proof of Concept for internal project.
Is there any way we can enable web connectivity to Windows server 2003 R2?
In other words I would like to connect to windows server using browser rather then remote desktop client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use logmein for connecting to the remote server. It can be accessed from any system's browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to configure "Remote Desktop Web Connection". Check out articles on [tech republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-manage-windows-server-2003-from-a-web-browser-with-remote-desktop-web-connection/5211392) and [petri](http://www.petri.co.il/install_remote_desktp_web_connection_on_windows_server_2003.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to a server using RDP without using the RDP client.  You need some form of RDP emulator to do this.  I have a server with Backspace which uses Citrix to allow browser control.

You are best going with a SAAS option like Logmein, Bomgar, or if you want to use a free one you can use Teamviewer for none commercial use.

Otherwise you have various config issues to go through on the server (as per Singleton' answer).  If you are in a corporate environment, you'll also likely have ISP / firewall issues to resolve.  If you're at a smaller company or home you may not have a static IP for your internet connection, so you'll then need to use something like dyndns & configure your router to update it with its new IP address as it updates.

Otherwise, you won't be able to reliably find your server from outside your LAN.